# How to judge the predict result of which SVM in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

For example I have 2 SVM objects SVMA and SVMB, they train different data set, and then I have a sample SAMPC.

```
int idx  = SVMA.predict(SAMPC);
int idx2 = SVMB.predict(SAMPC);
```

How to judge which SVM return the most similar result ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/43239/how-to-get-a-probability-for-a-svm-prediction/), and in the [predict() doco](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict) (assuming you have a 2 class SVM).

If you call predict() again, and set the parameter returnDFVal=true you will get the decision function value (the signed distance to the margin). You can use this to judge which result is "better".
The bigger the distance to the margin, the more likely it is that the sample belongs to the class to which it has been assigned.

Comment: Hi Bull. Understood. Thanks. I will remark your reply as an answer !